# Next JS ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT error after GraphQL mutation fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, graphql, apollo

So I'm using [Next JS API routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) and in one of such routes I'm calling a GraphQL mutation using Apollo, something like:

```js
// pages/api/foo.js

import { initializeApollo } from '~/server/apollo'

export default function handler(req, res) {
  const client = initializeApollo()
  try {
    await client.mutate({ mutation: FooDocument })
    // this works
    res.status(200).send({ foo: '...' })
  } catch {
    // this fails
    res.status(500).send({ error: '...' })
  }
}
```

as you can see if the mutation fails I get a server error when calling `res.status(500).send({ error: '...' })`:

> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

But If the mutation succeeds I got no error when calling `res.status(200).send({ foo: '...' })`.

Does anyone knows why this happens? I guess that my best alternative is to call this mutation only in the frontend but I would like to know if there's a way around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I see, I had a redirect in the `errorLink` of the `ApolloClient` configuration, it was hard to spot because this code was in a different file:

```js
const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors }) => {
  graphQLErrors.forEach(error => {
    if (err.message === 'foo') {
       // this redirect was the problem
       ctx.res.writeHead(307, { Location: '/somewhere' })
    }
  })
})
```

and so the `errorLink` was catching the error I was checking out and it was trying to do a redirect, that redirect was setting the headers and it was being ignored since I'm using the API routes. To solve this I just did an early return for that specific operation:

```js
const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, operation }) => {
  if (operation.operationName === 'MyMutation') {
    return
  }

  graphQLErrors.forEach(/*...*/);
})
```